# Find all permutations of values from lists with null hypothesis

Tags: python, matlab

I have several arrays. Each array consists of random values without redundancy and their length are random but limited.
For example, in the case of having maximum length of 4, I could have A = [1, 2, 3, 4], B = [1, 3], C = [2].
I would like to make a list of all permutations of values from arrays with null hypothesis. It should be :

```
[0 0 0] : take nothing from all lists.

[1 0 0] : take 1 from A and nothing from B and C.

[2 0 0]

[3 0 0]

[4 0 0]

[0 1 0] : take 1 from B and nothing from A and C.

[2 1 0] : take 2 from A and 1 from B and nothing from C. ([1 1 0] is not the case)

[3 1 0] [4 1 0]

[0 2 0] [1 2 0] [3 2 0] [4 2 0]

[0 0 2] [1 0 2] [3 0 2] ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like you could add zero to all the lists and then use itertools.

Comment: You included [0 2 0] as an example but B does not contain 2, does this mean that you want all permutations of the lists picked from [A B C] as well?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my mistake. [0 2 0], [1 2 0], [3 2 0], [4 2 0] are not the case.